# entity framework for xamarin in vs

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I want to use EF in xamarin in vs2015.
I create class library project with targets: [targets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcxOV.png)
and add the android app.
then I add two packages "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite" and "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore".
but when I run project this error is done:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll'
   at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() App1
```

how to resolve this error?

Comment: Please specify for what purpose you need to use entity framework in Xamarin

Comment: Have you read: https://blog.xamarin.com/building-android-apps-with-entity-framework/?